# 1-D numerical gradient for a 3-D array in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, gradient

I have a 3-D array (an image) of size (nrows x cols x ndivs), and I wish to calculate the 1-D numerical gradient along the 3rd dimension with a spacing of 0.01, and obtain (nrows x ncols) of sets of gradients.

I have thought of a way to do this by looping over every pixel:

```
grad_F = zeros(nrows,ncols,ndivs);

for irow = 1:nrows
    for icol = 1:ncols
        grad_F(irow,icol,:) = gradient(F(irow,icol,:),0.01);
    end
end
```

I would like to ask if there is an array operation for gradient to do the above without looping over every pixel? And if there is such a way, is it faster or will it take the same amount of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should work.

```
[~,~,FZ] = gradient(F,0.01)
```

FZ is your gradient in 3rd dimension.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! I thought that was referring to some other operation when I saw it on the matlab documentation.